# how can i create successfull popup window after register in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, ajax

[first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0MAp.jpg)

[second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td26k.jpg)

How can I create successful popup window?

Comment: Please share code from the calling side. If its an ajax based call share that part, as the question stands now its not good enough to answer.

Comment: We tend to discourage code supplied in images, since code is text, and is easier to work with if supplied in text format. To start with then, I would advise you to remove those images and replace it with formatted text. That said, there is no statement of what specific problem you are experiencing, and I wonder if your question is too broad anyway (and would thus be off-topic). Have you written any pop-up window code yet, or are you looking for help to get started?

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice question! They way you could do something like that would be.. to try and check what is your url - in this case is:

```
header("Location: ../Home.php?signup=success");
```

... and basically see if it contains the keyword "signup=success".
To do this, you need

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (strpos($url,'signup=success') !== false) {
    echo 'Thank you for signing up!';
} else {
    echo 'Something went wrong!';
}
```

Another way to do what you want, would be maybe with [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) or even better with [session variables](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) you can google them, but I have links for them to w3schools